# An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security

Tags: php, curl

I have an app that uses cURL to scrape some elements of sites.
I've started receiving some errors that look like this:

> "Not Acceptable!
>
> ## Not Acceptable!
>
> An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.
>
> "

Have you ever seen this?
If so, How can I get around it?

I checked 2 sites that do the same thing I do and everything worked fine

Regarding the cURL, this is what I use:

```
    public function cURL_scraping($url){
    $curl = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Expect:')); 
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'identity');
    $response['str'] = curl_exec($curl);  


    $response['header'] = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);



    curl_close($curl); 
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: What is the response when you try to open the url with a normal browser? What is the expected output?

Comment: With a normal browser i get a regular web page. No difference. I tried 2 sites on the same server and got the same response.

Answer (score 3):

Well I found the reason. I removed the user agent and it works. I guess the server was blocking this specific user agent.

Comment: Well,I added one and it worked! Thanks for the clue!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the site you are scraping has set up a detection and blocking of scraping. To check this you can try to get the webpage from the same ip and/or with all the same headers.

If that is the case, you really should respect the site owners wishes to not be scraped. You could ask them, or experiment to what is an acceptable scraping of their site. Did you read their `robots.txt`?

The error usually has a timeout, but it might be permanent. In that case you probably need to change ip address to try again.

Comment: It's not an IP issue for 2 reasons:
1 - checked on a few computers.
2 - other tools that do the same thing aren't blocked.
The thing is - it's my site doing the blocking :) however it's on a shared hosting and this could repeat itself on other sites...

Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried with exactly the same request from another ip, or `curl` from the command line? Are you able to reproduce the error outside of php?

Comment: I tried the same thing from another 2 IPs and got the same issue. The issue is only within a script. not with a regular http request

Answer (score 1):

I got same error and I was just playing around and found an answer.

If you understand some basic python, it will be easy for you to change related code in in the language that you are working with.

I just added a header like this,

```
headers = {
    "User-Agent":
        "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

And this works!